# Python: Get another key value if one key does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a dictionary as below:

```
mapping = {"a": 1, "b": None, "c": 2}
```

I would want to get the value of `b` if it exists and if not then the value of `c`.

I can do it like this:

```
map_value = ""
if mapping["b"]:
    map_value = mapping["b"]
elif mapping["c"]:
    map_value = mapping["c"]
```

But can I do it one line something like `get` function?

Comment: Your example is not consistent with your question. Besides, it does not address the case when `mapping["c"]` is None.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the if-else operator.

You seem to contradict yourself in the question, so I am going to consider two interpretations. If you want to check whether the key *exists*, use this solution:

```
mapping['b'] if ('b' in mapping) else mapping['c']
#None
```

The latter can be also written as:

```
mapping.get("b", mapping["c"])
#None
```

If you want to check whether the value of `mapping["b"]` is *not None*, use this solution:

```
mapping['b'] if (mapping['b'] is not None) else mapping['c']
#2
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method allows passing a default value.

You can do something like that by nesting `get` calls:

```py
mapping = {"a": 1, "b": None, "c": 2}
mapping.get("d", mapping.get("c"))
# 2
```

Comment: If the value stored for the key is None then, in that case, it's not returning a default value, the default value is returned only when the key is not found where as key "b" exist and it has value stored as None

Answer (score 0):

You mention to "get the value of 'b' if it exists"; but it seems like you mean `if b is not falsey` based on the code you have. You can do that like:

```py
map_value = mapping["b"] or mapping["c"]
```

If the keys are not guaranteed to exist, then:

```py
map_value = mapping.get("b") or mapping.get("c")
```

In the second example, using `get`, if `b` is not a key in `mapping`, or `b`'s value is `None`, it will use `c`'s value (if `c` is a key in `mapping`) else it will be None. If you need the default to be `""` as in your example, you can just add another `or ""`.

Word of caution, if "b" is another "falsey" value (aside from None) and you want to preserve that value, then this won't work (but then that is also the case with your example code).

Ex:

```py
mapping = {"a": 1, "b": 0, "c": 2}
map_value = mapping.get("b") or mapping.get("c")
print(map_value)  # prints 2
```